# Conditional associated record deletion in afterDelete()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the following setup:

Models:

```
Team
Task
Change
TasksTeam
```

`TasksTeam` is a hasManyThrough, that associates teams to tasks.  `Change` is used to record changes in the details of tasks, including when teams are attached/detached (i.e. through records in `TasksTeam`).

`TasksTeam` also cascades deletes of `Task`.  If a task is deleted, all related team associations should also be deleted.

When a `TasksTeam` is deleted, it means a team has left a task, and I'd like to record a `Change` for that.  I'm using the `TasksTeam afterDelete()` to record teams leaving.  In the `TasksTeam beforeDelete` I save the data to `$this->predelete` so it'll be available in the `afterDelete()`.

Here is the non-working code in `TasksTeam`:

```
public function afterDelete(){
    $team_id = $this->predelete['TasksTeam']['team_id'];
    $task_role_id = $this->predelete['TasksTeam']['task_role_id'];
    $task_id = $this->predelete['TasksTeam']['task_id'];

    // Wanted: only record a change if the task isn't deleted
    if($this->Task->exists($task_id)){
        $this->Task->Change->removeTeamFromTask($task_id, $team_id, $task_role_id);    
    }    
    return true;
}
```

**Problem:**

When a task is deleted, the delete cascades to `TasksTeam` correctly.  However, **a change will be recorded even if the Task is deleted**.  From another answer to something similar on SO, I think the reason is that the callbacks are called before `Model:del()`, meaning the task hasn't yet been deleted when it hits `TasksTeam` `afterDelete()`

**Question**

How can I successfully save a `Change` only if the task isn't deleted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @James Dunne I ended up adding a tinyint field to the `Task` model called `is_deleted` and simply set this boolean true in the `Task` `beforeDelete()`.  I then check for this flag and only save a `Change` if the flag is boolean false. It seems wasteful to add a field for something that is only affected just before the record is deleted, but for my purposes it works fine.  I think a "real solution" would involve the [Cake Events System](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) , avoiding the need for chained callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If the callbacks are getting called before the actual delete, I see maintaining an assoc. array of flags with task IDs as keys, or a set of task IDs, which are added when `afterDelete` is called on `Task`. Then you could create a method in `Task`, such as `isDeleting` or similar, which queries the array, to tell you if the task is in the process of being deleted.